# Invoke a system command from R with dynamic variable name

Tags: r, system

I want to call python script using the system command. I am passing a parameter with it, but the variable is dynamic. I am not sure how to paste the filename dynamically. I would like the Filename to be changed depending on the user input.

```
system('python testMethod.py Filename', wait = TRUE)
```

Comment: Wrap system in a function that takes user input or use some system level reader/prompt?

Comment: Just paste the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `paste0` to create the command string:

```
filenname <- "Filename"
system(paste0("python testMethod.py ", filename), wait = TRUE)
```

**Edit:**
M--'s suggestion does make it cleaner:

```
filenname <- "Filename"
system(paste("python testMethod.py", filename), wait = TRUE)
```

Comment: Use `paste` instead of `paste0` and get rid of that manually entered space at the end of first string. That's cleaner.

Comment: also `paste` is more portable than `paste0` to older versions of R